# AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP Not Waking Device?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've been trying to use AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP to wake up my device to play some sounds. 
Here's the alarm scheduling:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, OneShotAlarm.class); 
PendingIntent sender =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, intent, 0); 

// I want the alarm to go off 60 seconds from now. 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); 

// Schedule the alarm! 
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

---

The OneShotAlarm BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(context, "OneShotAlarm Broadcast invoked", 1000).show(); 

        intent = new Intent(context, ServiceClassToRun.class); 

        context.startService(intent); 
    } 
}
```

---

The Service:

```
public class ServiceClassToRun extends Service { 
    protected static final int Rnd = 0; 

     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) { 
     //do some business here 
}
```

---

And finally, my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".OneShotAlarm" android:process=":remote" /> 
<service android:name=".ServiceClassToRun "/>
```

My service works fine when device is in wake up state.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Has anyone else experienced this as 
well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you wrote all the permission ?

Answer (score 4):

```
PendingIntent sender =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

change to

```
PendingIntent sender =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

OR, If you miss the permission of alarm, than add these permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Let me know, If it's work for you

Comment: Is is helps me to switch on my mobile at the alarm triggered time.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is still relevant for the author, but maybe it will be useful for someone else.
Probably the reason for the issue is that you do not acquire any wakelocks. System holds a wakelock for you while OneShotAlarm.onReceive is called. You start a service by sending an intent. But after the OneShotAlarm.onReceive returns, there are no held wakelocks left and the device goes to sleep. Therefore your intent will be only delivered when you manually wake up the device.

You can see an example with a wakelock here https://github.com/yuriykulikov/AlarmClock/blob/develop/src/com/better/alarm/model/AlarmsService.java

Best regards,
Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

Your Service - ServiceClassToRun will be called 1 minute after you have set the alarm..But you won't come to know it as you havn't done anything in onStart() method.Also override onBind and onCreate methods.

You may implement Notification or play sound when onStart method of Service is called

You can ask if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks for quick ans.Actually I have not shown that part of code as my question will become lengthy .My service works fine when device is in wake up state.

Comment: Then what is problem? use notification along with alarm